# How to run an Oracle Query for another timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I have an Oracle database set up in CST -6 and my dates are stored in that time zone.  I'd like to run a single query and return any dates in a different time zone, PST -8.  Is this possible?

```
select start_date, end_date from user_record;

Current: 2015-12-01 03:34:46    2015-12-01 04:23:10
Expected: 2015-12-01 01:34:46   2015-12-01 02:23:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New_time function converts a date and time from one time zone to another in oracle.

```
SELECT NEW_TIME (TO_DATE ('2015-12-01 03:34:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'),
                 'CST',
                 'PST'
                )
FROM DUAL;

Output: 12/1/2015 1:34:46 AM
```

Hope it helps

Comment: new_time exists in Oracle since Oracle 9i. FYR: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions092.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select 
    start_date AT TIME ZONE '-08:00', 
    end_date AT TIME ZONE '-08:00'
from user_record;
```